# In UWP, how can I reset an app’s data?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, reset

I know that in order to reset an app’s data, I have to open the Settings app from Start menu. Head to System > Apps & Features, locate the app, then click the "Advance Options" and tap Reset but I want to achieve this by code. I think I have to call this line but I don't know if I have to do something else: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync()

Comment: Just read the documentation of that method - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_ClearAsync

Comment: Slightly easier is just right click and uninstall from start menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clear all the application data from the local, roaming and temporary folders.

```
await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync();
```

Answer (score 4):

As the document [ClearAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_ClearAsync) method,

> Removes all application data from the local, roaming, and temporary app data stores.

If a UWP app is installed, there will be the following folders in the app package folder of the `AppData` folder in your device.

[image]

When you use **Advance Options** and **Reset**, all the app data your app puts into all these folders will be cleared, but the behavior of using the `await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync()` method will just delete the data in `LocalCache`, `LocalState`, `RoamingState` and `TempState` folders including the [LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalSettings).

Usually, we just operate the data in above four folders in the Application data locations when we develop our apps, so this [ClearAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_ClearAsync) method should satisfy our requirement that clearing the application data.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the Data, you should do:

1. find the settings file(and other temp files), only you know where these files is.
   such as this:
   [image]
2. delete these files in your reset code.
3. restart your app.

hope help.